# Https on JSF 2, for protected resources and login

Tags: java, https, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I have a managed bean with 2 attribute: `userName` & `password` (with its respective getters and setters methods), and a `login()` method that access the database to verify login credentials.

My question is, when the user clicks the "login" button, the action must go through https protocol. How can I achieve this with JSF 2?

Also, if I want to have some Faces to be protected (under https protocol), how do I achieve this? Is there a filter that enables me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a security constraint in the web.xml of your application:

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>SecureConnection</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint/>
      <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Adapt the url-pattern to contain your login page and all other secured pages. The use of https is defined by the user-data-constraint.

From the [Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html):

> If you specify CONFIDENTIAL or
>   INTEGRAL as a security constraint, it
>   generally means that the use of SSL is
>   required and applies to all requests
>   that match the URL patterns in the web
>   resource collection, not just to the
>   login dialog box.

If you wrote your own login() method and are using Glassfish, you could take a look at container-based authentication with a [JDBCRealm](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/jdbcrealm_in_glassfish) as alternative login approach.